# Can I download music from itunes web site without itunes software?

Tags: music, downloads, itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I download iTunes podcasts with hpodder or other software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169613/how-do-i-download-itunes-podcasts-with-hpodder-or-other-software)

There is a bunch of free courses [available](http://www.openculture.com/freeonlinecourses) on the net. But a lot of them are available only through iTunes, even if they are free, including [one that interests me](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/hannibal/id384234015?mt=10#ls=1). There is no way I install iTunes on my computer (not that I can't, but I won't). Is there a workaround (ex : user-agent?) to download the files anyway?

Comment: Use Tunesviewer, see my answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/169613/how-do-i-download-itunes-podcasts-with-hpodder/169699#169699

Comment: I don't think that there is a way. You can always install itunes, download them and save the files somewhere else and delete the program. But what exactly are you trying to download? Is it a video or audio? perhaps if you specify exactly which course you are trying to download someone can find a workaround.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.10, Rhythmbox lets you search and subscribe iTunes podcasts. (Podcasts -> Add) Unfortunately it doesn't search iTunesu, and crashes often. Hope it's fixed before final release :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Currently, iTunes will not work, not properly at least, with Wine or Playonlinux or Crossover (it used to work a while ago). What **will** work, though, is to install Windows in [VirtualBox](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/virtualbox-ose), and install iTunes on top of that installation. This is a bit of an overkill for iTunes, but if you have Windows installed in a vbox anyways then it does not cost you too much trouble.
2. iTunes is absolutely required to access iTunes if you want to buy music. No alternatives exist. However, as I was informed in a comment -- [other software exists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169613/how-do-i-download-itunes-podcasts-with-hpodder-or-other-software/169699) to access free contents.
3. For some type of the media, there are alternatives to iTunes. For example, you can buy music from Ubuntu One music store or Amazon. I am well aware that this will not replace iTunes Music Store, but you can get music from the Big Four in these stores as well.

Comment: A program called Tunesviewer allows you to access free material from Itunes U or any of the free podcasts. The op refers to free material in his question- he means podcasts rather than music.

Comment: That's cool! I didn't know that.